Complete residue system of $\nu_2(n!)$ in $\pmod m$.
Let $\nu_2(n!)$ denote the largest power of $2$ that divides $n!$. Prove that for all natural numbers $a$ and $m$, there exists a natural number $n$ ($n > 1$) such that $\nu_2(n!) \equiv a \pmod{m}$
This problem I found in one of my old math olympiad preperation set of problems. It basically wants us to prove that $\nu_2(n!)$ is a complete residue $\pmod m$ over all positive integers $n$. First, I thought about Legendre's formula
$$\nu_2(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\text{log}_2n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor$$
Then, taking $n$ is a power of $2$, you get $\nu_2(n!)=n-1$. So here's where I got stuck. Maybe we could use Chinese Remainder Theorem? I don't know.

The $\sum_{i=1}^{\text{log}_2n}$ is incomplete.

Sorry, my bad. I'll try to be more careful next time. Thanks for pointing this out!

Continuing from what you did, i.e., with $n = 2^x$ for some non-negative integer $x$ means $\nu_2(n!) = n - 1$, consider instead $n$ being just one less, so the number of factors of $2$ in $n!$ would be $x$ less, i.e.,
$$n = 2^{x} - 1 \;\;\to\;\; \nu_2(n!) = (n - 1) - x = 2^{x} - x - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
We'll prove there's always a positive integer $x$ where
$$2^x - x - 1 \equiv a \pmod{m} \iff 2^x - x \equiv a + 1 \pmod{m} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
The following is based on Post #$7$ (of the AoPS thread A^x + x = b (mod c)) which gives the official solution to a Brazilian Math Olympiad $2005$ problem. Let $l$ be the cycle length of $2, 2^2, 2^3, \ldots \mod m$, i.e.,
$$2^{i + lk} \equiv 2^{i} \pmod{m} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
for all positive integers $k$ and large enough integers $i$. Next, let
$$d = \gcd(l, m) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Consider if $d = m$. Since $d\mid l$, then $m \mid l \;\to\; l \ge m$. However, each congruence value within the cycle must be unique (since, otherwise, $a^i\equiv a^j$ means $a^{i+t}\equiv a^{j+t}$ for all $t \ge 0$, i.e., $j - i$ is an integral multiple of $l$). Thus, we have $l \le m$. Since we got $l \ge m$ earlier, this means $l = m$. Then $a^i \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$ for some $i$, i.e., $m$ divides $a^i$. However, then $m$ divides $a^i$ for each larger $i$. Hence, then $l = 1$, so $m = 1$. Thus, if $m \gt 1$, then since $d \le m$, we must have $d \lt m$.
Next, we'll use induction on $m$. First, \eqref{eq2A} obviously has a solution for $m = 1$. Suppose $m \gt 1$ and \eqref{eq2A} has a solution for all positive integers less than $m$. Then it must also have a solution for $d \lt m$. By the induction hypothesis, there are sufficiently large integers $s_0, s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{d-1}$ such that
$$2^{s_i} - s_i \equiv i \pmod{d} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
for every $i = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, d - 1$. Next, let
$$a + 1 = qd + r, \;\; 0 \le r \lt d \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
From \eqref{eq5A}, we get for some integer $t$ that $2^{s_r} - s_r = r + td$. Using this and \eqref{eq3A}, we get
$$2^{s_r + lk} - (s_r + lk) \equiv 2^{s_r} - (s_r + lk) \equiv r + td - lk \pmod{m} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
But note that when $k$ varies, $lk \pmod{m}$ goes through all multiples of $d$. This is because we have for any integer $y$ that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& lk \equiv yd \pmod{m} \iff \left(\frac{l}{d}\right)k \equiv y \pmod{\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)} \\
& \iff k \equiv y\left(\frac{l}{d}\right)^{-1} \pmod{\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$
with the inverse of $\frac{l}{d}$ existing modulo $\frac{m}{d}$ since, from \eqref{eq4A}, we get $\gcd\left(\frac{l}{d}, \frac{m}{d}\right) = 1$.
Thus, there exists an integer $k$ such that, with $y = -q + t$ in \eqref{eq8A}, we get $lk \equiv (-q + t)d \pmod{m}$. Plugging this into \eqref{eq7A}, and using \eqref{eq6A}, gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& 2^{s_r + lk} - (s_r + lk) \equiv r + td - (-q + t)d \pmod{m} \\
& \iff 2^{s_r + lk} - (s_r + lk) \equiv r + qd = a + 1 \pmod{m}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$
Hence, the induction step is complete, with $x = s_r + lk$ being a solution for \eqref{eq2A}, and $n$ then being determined by \eqref{eq1A}.

See my solution here for a slightly cleaner (to me) induction solution.
